# HTML & CSS - Text stick to bottom of div?

Tags: html, css

I am making a "Starcraft II" website for my clan. I want the navigation bar to contain the text "ALLOYE" and stick to the bottom of the navigation bar. I have tried this code:

```css
vertical-align: text-bottom;
```

But the text seems to say about 10 pixels over the bottom. Is it because of some hidden border or something?
This is my total HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
  <body>
     <div class="nav">
        <div class="title">
           <strong>ALLOYE</strong>
        </div>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, Sans-Serif;
}
.nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 7%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFB441, #FF9A00);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFB441, #FF9A00);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFB441, #FF9A00);
  background: linear-gradient(#FFB441, #FF9A00);
}
.title {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align:text-bottom;
  font-size: 65px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.nav` height (7%) is likely causing the overlap. If you set this to `px` instead of a `%` you should be able to force the 'ALLOYE' below the bar.

Something like the below:

```css
.nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  background: linear-gradient(#FFB441, #FFAC2F, #FF9A00);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you temporarily set a border on both classes, you will see what is happening.

Once you see that, try putting the 7% height onto the .title instead.

Then do the following to see what happens:

- change the height of your browser window to very short heights.
- look in different browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox etc)
- look at it on your phone
- Press F12 when in your browser and experiment

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like:

```css
.nav{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: linear-gradient(#FFB441, #FFAC2F, #FF9A00);
}
.title {
  position: absolute;        
  font-size: 65px; /* This large a font has significant whitespace at the bottom */
  bottom: -15px; /* Compensate for font whitespace. Tweak to fit your font /*
}
```

But other than that, as Ruskin suggests in his answer, you probably want to set a fixed height on your navigation.

Comment: The whole nav bar disappered.

Comment: The disappearing nav bar is because positioning an element absolutely takes it out of the flow of the page, causein the bar to be empty, and collapse. If you want to prevent it, set a height in pixels as previously suggested. I've made an edit regarding the unwanted space below the text.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think you need a [reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), as I am not seeing the space in my jsFiddle with no changes to your code (http://jsfiddle.net/R6dTU/).

Then I'd follow a different approach here. I'd position the title so that it is

```css
.title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

I'd also recommend not using percentage heights without a min-height, unless you don't mind your text being cropped off screen.

Also, keep in mind that [vertical-align: text-bottom;](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/) aligns the text to the bottom of the descenders (e.g., the tails on lower case p's and q's), so you will not quite get the effect you're looking for with this. Position absolute is more reliable.

Per @ANeves's comment, The reset is not the 'best practice' solution here, but it may be a quick fix. The proper solution would be to

- Use a proper tag for your header text. divs should only be for elements that cannot be otherwise classified. I'd suggest a h1 tag here
- Set margins and padding on this tag, and set a line-height, otherwise, it may change between browsers (this is what the reset is a quick fix for)

Comment: I strongly oppose the indiscriminate use of CSS resets.

Comment: I personally don't use them either but I think they're a good starting place for people just getting into development, or quick one off sites.

Comment: That is precisely it: I think they are a very bad starting point.[1]  They will allow you to get rid of a problem without really fixing it. Here is a suitable programmer's adage: `When the only tool you know is C++, everything looks like a thumb.` - replace "C++" with "CSS Reset". ([1]: A "worst practice", even. I appreciate the edit you did on the answer.)

Comment: Ah... Well, the real problem is that the browsers are all implemented differently. If you use a reset without understanding what it does, you will still get better results at the expense of a tiny performance hit. I think it's the lesser of two evils.

Answer (score 0):

Use the bottom CSS property on the element containing the absolute positioning property (in this case, it's `<code>.nav</code>`). Set the bottom property's attribute to 0%. Your CSS should look something like this:

```css
.nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `height: 7%;` from `.nav` and add it to `.title`:
(Updated CSS):

```css
body {
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Segoe UI",Arial,Sans-Serif;
}
.nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#FFB441, #FFAC2F, #FF9A00);
}
.title {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align:text-bottom;
  font-size: 65px;
  height: 7%;
}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Wae6n/3/